# MVC Razor Radio Button

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**In partial view** 
I work with textboxes like this.

```
@model Dictionary<string, string>
@Html.TextBox("XYZ", @Model["XYZ"])
```

How can i generate radiobuttons, and get the desired value in the form collection as YES/NO True/False) ? Currently i am getting null for "ABC" if i select any value for the below.

```
   <label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", @Model["ABC"])Yes</label>
   <label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", @Model["ABC"])No</label>
```

**Controller**

```
        public int Create(int Id, Dictionary<string, string> formValues)
        {
         //Something Something
        }
```

Comment: Show your action method code as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Yes/No Radio Buttons with Strongly Bound Model MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559208/asp-net-mvc-yes-no-radio-buttons-with-strongly-bound-model-mvc)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In order to do this for multiple items do something like:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "Yes") @:Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "No") @:No
}
```

Comment: I call all my partial views passing @model Dictionary<string, string> i need a way to return (True, False) or (Yes,No) for selected values in radio buttons.

Comment: @KirkWoll his code wouldn't bind to a `Dictionary<string, string>` (as his model states). Based on a Yes No response, a bool is probably best, a Nullable bool if you're allowing none to be selected though.

Comment: @KirkWoll Check my updated edit, I originally thought he just wanted a Yes No for one option, thus recommending a bool.

Comment: I don't want to change my model, i want to keep @model Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: @Nikhil Ah well that's fine, you'll have either "Yes" or "No" as the values then (or `null` if nothing was selected). Try my updated edit and keep your model as `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: @Nikhil no problems glad I could help :)

Comment: @:No / @:Yes is not working ( ':' is not allowed as a start of razor expression ) - maybe cause im not using loop

Comment: @MichaelBrennt The "@:" is used to break out of Razor, similar to the `<text>` tag as Yes and No are basically HTML/non-C# code (you may not need it depending on your structure).

Comment: It doesn't preserve field's state on postbacks if there's an error in the form.

Answer (score 25):

Simply :

```
   <label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", True)Yes</label>
   <label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", False)No</label>
```

But you should always use strongly typed model as suggested by cacho.

Comment: You have to be careful as none of the posted solutions perform any kind of server-side validation. Here's an elegant solution that performs both client-side and server-side validation to ensure valid data is posted to the model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185910/3960200

Answer (score 15):

I solve the same problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2559570/376382) SO answer.

Basically it binds the radio button to a boolean property of a Strongly Typed Model.

```
@Html.RadioButton("blah", !Model.blah) Yes 
@Html.RadioButton("blah", Model.blah) No
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

I done this in a way like:

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "M", false)@Html.Label("Male")
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "F", false)@Html.Label("Female")
```

Answer (score 10):

**MVC5** Razor Views

Below example will also associate labels with radio buttons (radio button will be selected upon clicking on the relevant label)

```
// replace "Yes", "No" --> with, true, false if needed
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Compatible, "Yes", new { id = "compatible" })
@Html.Label("compatible", "Compatible")

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Compatible, "No", new { id = "notcompatible" })
@Html.Label("notcompatible", "Not Compatible")
```

Comment: This is the better answer because it addresses the rendering of unique id attributes.

Answer (score 8):

```
<label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", "YES")Yes</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButton("ABC", "NO")No</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

MVC Razor provides one elegant Html Helper called **RadioButton** with two parameters (this is general, But we can overload it uptil five parameters) i.e. one with the group name and other being the value

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    Male:   @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male")
    Female: @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female")
</div>
```

Comment: Explain your solution please.

Answer (score 3):

```
<p>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.type, "Item1")Item1</p>
<p>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.type, "Item2")Item2</p>
<p>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.type, "Item3")Item3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
@{ var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "checked", "" } }; }
@Html.RadioButtonFor(_ => _.BoolProperty, true, (@Model.BoolProperty)? dic: null) Yes
@Html.RadioButtonFor(_ => _.BoolProperty, false, (!@Model.HomeAddress.PreferredMail)? dic: null) No
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share one way to do the radio button (and entire HTML form) without using the @Html.RadioButtonFor helper, although I think @Html.RadioButtonFor is probably the better and newer way (for one thing, it's strongly typed, so is closely linked to theModelProperty). Nevertheless, here's an old-fashioned, different way you can do it:

```
    <form asp-action="myActionMethod" method="post">
        <h3>Do you like pizza?</h3>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input asp-for="likesPizza"/> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This code can go in a myView.cshtml file, and also uses classes to get the radio-button (checkbox) formatting.