# how to change a checkbox to 2 radio buttons. Value doesn't pass back 'true'

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My table in the DB contains 2 fields. 'Title' and 'IsBusiness'(which is stored as a bool on wether the record is a business account or not.

When adding a new record on screen the editorFor is used to display a checkbox for 'IsBusiness' which passes back true or false.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsBusiness)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IsBusiness)
```

I want to change this to 2 radio buttons. 'Product' and 'Business' which passes back false if product is selected and true is business is selected.

So far my code below keeps passing back false. It wont store 'True'...any ideas?

```
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, "Business")Business</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, "Product")Product</label>
```

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, "Business") and @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, "Product") will add 2 radio buttons with same ID

Comment: I only want 'T' or 'F' to be passed back depending on which radio box is chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, true) Business</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusiness, false) Product</label>
```

See also: [ASP.NET MVC Yes/No Radio Buttons with Strongly Bound Model MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559208/asp-net-mvc-yes-no-radio-buttons-with-strongly-bound-model-mvc)