# Correct Way to Code a Group of Radio Buttons using RadioButtonFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, radio-button, radiobuttonfor

Based on my research, the correct way to code a checkbox in MVC is as follows.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
```

This will render a checkbox, render a label for the checkbox, and make the label *clickable*, which means clicking the label also toggles the checkbox.

But what about the case where there are multiple checkboxes for a single view-model field? (For example, maybe each checkbox represents a bit within an integer value.) Or, better yet, what about radio buttons, where there are always several options associated with the same field?

In these cases, there seems to be issues with the code above. Either not all elements would be associated with the same field, or multiple elements with the same ID would be rendered.

I have been researching this for a while now. I have found many solutions; however, they all seem to either not have a clickable label, or they require a bunch of custom and/or non-standard coding. Some avoid the use of RadioButtonFor/LabelFor completely, choosing instead to code the raw HTML.

Coding the raw HTML is fine, but didn't the designers of MVC not anticipate that we may need multiple radio buttons for the same field? And, if they did, how did they intended it to be coded?

**EDIT:**

After researching this some more, the code below is the best way I've found to code radio buttons. This code assumes I've defined an enum for each of my radio options.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Male, new { id = "gender-male" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Male.ToString(), new { @for = "gender-male" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Female, new { id = "gender-female" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Female.ToString(), new { @for = "gender-female" })
```

Maybe this is the best I can expect, but it still troubles me a little.

1. Why is so much customization for basic stuff such as IDs required? Again, didn't Microsoft anticipate that we'd want multiple radio buttons associated with the same field?
2. if the enum name isn't the same as the description I want for the radio button label, this approach doesn't seem to support field attributes such as `[Display(Name = "")]`.

(I guess the correct handling of multiple checkboxes will be deferred to another question.)

Comment: In my opinion `RadioButtonFor` should have overloads like `DropDownListFor` where I can pass a list of items and radio buttons for each item would be generated with clickable labels.

Comment: @th1rdey3: I'm not sure about *DropDownListFor*. Maybe *RadioButtonListFor*? And [such a component has been written](http://mvccbl.com/), if you'd like to use a third-party option. But I can't understand why Microsoft didn't think it was needed.

Comment: And now you are talking alone... About the question the solution you found I think it's something... meanwhile.

Comment: Just pointing AmirHosseinMehrvarzi deleted all his comments. That's it.

Comment: @JonathanWood Btw, what did you do on SO on Jan 1 at 2:56?? Why don't you celebrate New Year? :)

Comment: @JonathanWood: this possibly *could* be done using a jquery/javascript, but I do agree if a "radio group box" was included, it'd be beneficial? [But i saw this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559208/asp-net-mvc-yes-no-radio-buttons-with-strongly-bound-model-mvc)

Comment: @Sergio: Ha, I assume that was 2:56 PM. What can I say? I do program in my free time, and I have some side work I have to fit in to my free time. But I also had some fun during the holidays. :)

Comment: @jbutler483: Thanks for the link to the other question. Does't quite answer mine, but some good info there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, let's do some research. First of all, you don't need unique id to toggle checkbox/radio by clicking a label. Actually you don't need *id* at all! All you have to do is wrap your input inside `<label>` tag:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" /> Radio 1   
</label>
```

So far so good, ASP.NET MVC provides you ability to code your own html helpers, let's write one for `Enum` model field!

Imagine, we've got some registration model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
}
```

Damn! I've just copy-pasted tutorial model o_O. What we want now - is to get user's gender, so we add a `Gender` enum:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Iamparanoic = 0,

    Male = 1,

    Female = 2,
}
```

and add `Gender` field of `Gender` type to our model (wish, c# had a `Gender` access modifier!)

```
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

Now, time to use some asp.net magic and write our html helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonsListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<ul>"); //we want it to look cool, dont' we?
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value).ToHtmlString(); //you can generage any id and pass it to helper, or use a tagbuilder

        sb.AppendFormat(
            "<li><label>{0} {1}</label></li>",
            radio,
            ((Enum)value).GetEnumName() //instead of it you can grab e.g. Display/Description attribute value or w/e else
        );
    }
    sb.Append("</ul");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

and usage of that will look like:

```
@Html.RadioButtonsListForEnum(m => m.Gender)
```

So pretty, isn't it? Of course you can add hella lot's of customization, like rendering radiobuttons with unique mvc-style id's, all kindes of html attributes etc. but this is just a sample, ass kick to right way.

Next, we also want to render checkboxlist!

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var enumValue = Convert.ToInt32(metadata.Model);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum)))
    {
        var val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");

        checkbox.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("value", value.ToString());
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("name", htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToString());

        if ((enumValue & val) == val)
            checkbox.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
        if (htmlAttributes != null)
            checkbox.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        var label = new TagBuilder("label") { InnerHtml = checkbox + ((Enum)value).GetEnumName() };

        sb.Append(label);
        sb.Append("<br/>");
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

And again, simple usage:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListForEnum(m => m.Gender)
```

Btw, it makes sence just for enums marked with `Flags` attribute, and of course you'll have troubles with model binding - it requires custom binder. But it's another question, and i hope [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) can answer it :)

Comment: Plus 1 for the talking about including the checkbox within the `<label>` element, which doesn't require a unique ID. I am familiar with this approach but had read it was not recommended. However, researching it now, it appears that either approach is equally valid. Regarding a custom HtmlHelper, I've written a pretty sophisticated one, as I've indicated in the discussions here. Mine will also use any [Description] attribute for the enum values, if one is available. And my checkbox version supports a list of initially selected values.

Comment: I'm still at a complete loss as to why there wasn't some basic support for this included with MVC. In fact, even using your technique of wrapping the `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` within a `<Labe>` element is invalid because it will generate duplicate IDs. Even if that works, it's bad form.

Comment: @JonathanWood actually i've noticed that it's just a sample. Hope you can figure out how to generate unique id using model metadata and current enum value? Also, you can customize helper the way you need it, using htmlattributes, wrapping/or not to `ul`

Comment: Why there's no basic support for it in MVC? Because most of the time people don't need it? And if you really do - you can code it yourself, same as custom dropdownlists, special labels and so on...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, i believe nothing to be done from Microsoft side to handle the case you are talking about.

starting from the Html code, how in html, the multi radio buttons will be presented?

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

above is a sample I brought it from [W3cSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio),

if you want to toggle the radio button by clicking the label, this can be done in two ways in html

first way is to use the for tag in the label

```
<input type="radio" id="myId" name="MyName" value="MyValue" />
<label for="myId">Display Name</label>
```

second way is to put the radio input inside a label tag

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" id="myId" name="MyName" value="MyValue"/> 
   Display Name
</label>
```

as you can see, its combination of tags to get the radio button toggles when you click on the label, Microsoft i think kept it simple and flexible to the developer to choose what to do and in the way he likes it.

now, to get the same result in Mvc, either you hard code each radio button you have in one of these 2 methods mentioned above, or to make it more easy, write your own Mvc Html extension, and I recommend the second method.

hope this will help you

Comment: With this mindset, there is not reason for MVC's `CheckboxFor`, `LabelFor` or other HTML helpers. Microsoft felt they were worthwhile, and many people are using them. Clearly, they are useful. Here, support is just a bit lacking.

Comment: I agree with you, that if we generalize the idea, sure i will come to same result as you wrote, but in your case there is 2 ideas that another program wants the result in different way than you want, he doesn't want to toggle the checkbox when the user clicks on the label, and you want it to be toggled when the user clicks on the label, for simplicity and as you know, this is kind of framework for mvc, Microsoft will provide the basic things and it is not a lack, in my opinion

Comment: I agree with @HadiHassan that Microsoft gives basic controls, In winforms applications, we get to used on the controls that doesn't support all our needs, and as a result, we were obliged to buy a third party tool.