# Why does my convert to bool not work c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project that has a radio button.  Im using a custom input so it looks a bit like this.

```
<input class="cb_yes" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select" id="radio_Yes" name="RadioButton" type="radio" value="True">
<span id="radio-yes"></span>Yes</label>
<input class="cb_no" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select" id="radio_No" name="RadioButton" type="radio" value="False">
<span id="radio-no"></span>No</label>
```

Notice that the `name` is the same.

When Yes is clicked, in the browser console I can do

`$("input[name='RadioButton']").val()` and it came back as `True`. So far so good.

I'm then doing some C# to convert this value to a c# bool.

I'm doing

`IsAlreadyCustomer = Convert.ToBoolean(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"] == "True");`

but it's coming back as `false`. I'm looking in the "QuickWatch" to test and doing

`controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"] == "True"` but thats, no suprise, false.

I cant seem to see why it's coming back as false. I dont get why my browser says True but QuickWatch is saying false

Have I wrote it correctly? What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Update:

First, I'm declaring a bool, then I try to set the bool to true based on the value of the radio button.

```
bool IsAlreadyCustomer;
   //if null then false, else         
 IsAlreadyCustomer = Convert.ToBoolean(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"] == "True");`
        `
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `Form["RadioButton"]` to see what the value is?

Comment: yea. "Form doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: I meant with all the preceding junk too. Just examine the value of what you're trying to compare to "True".

Comment: As long as the submitted form data has `RadioButton: True` in the body, your code should generate `true` for the `IsAlreadyCustomer` variable.

Comment: BTW, You do not need the `Convert.ToBoolean` call as the `==` expression will return a boolean value.

Comment: @itsme86 yes I did just `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"] == "True"` and it came back `"False"`

Comment: No, I mean examine the value. You're examining the comparison result. What does `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"]` evaluate to? `<something> == "True"` is false, but what's the <something>?

Comment: In my code, I'm setting IsAreadyCustomer to the value of the radio button. Ive declared `IsAlreadyCustomer` as a bool. Then setting it using the code above. It should be coming back as True but its being set to false. I'll update my question for more info

Comment: You're not setting `IsAlreadyCustomer` to the value of the radio button though. You're setting it to the result of comparing the value of the radio button to "True".

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method. Run to the breakpoint. Go to the `Immediate Window` and evaluate `?controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["RadioButton"]` What **exactly** does it display?

Comment: @mjwills it comes back as `"False"` (as a string)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of doing it all in the hardest way possible, you should (1) create and use a **Model class**, (2) use **HTML Helpers** for rendering the HTML output, and (3) use **Model Binding** instead of messing around with Request.Form. For examples of how to do that, see e.g. **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2559208/1220550)**.

Comment: @PeterB Unfortunatley that option isnt available for me