# RadioButtonFor always pass true to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

*I found answers to similar questions in many places but it didn't work with me even by copy/paste the code*!

I am developing an MVC/C# application and I have a I have a bool property like the following:

`public bool IsMarried { get; set; }`

On the view side, I have the following code to represent the property:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMarried , true)Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMarried , false)No
</label>
```

My problem is whwnever I submit the form, I get all of the rest of the normal fields (text) except the boolean property is always `true`

As I mentioned, there are many solutions I found such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559208/asp-net-mvc-yes-no-radio-buttons-with-strongly-bound-model-mvc) but I don't know why it didn't work for me.

---

Added by author:

I wanted to add to this question to make everything visible. In addition to the code I am showing above, I am using `Ajax` to submit the form.

**This is the Ajax code:**

```
function SaveWebFormToDatabase() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    //Append the other textboxes with the form data
    formData.append("LastName", $("#LastName").val());
    formData.append("FirstName", $("#FirstName").val());
    formData.append("IsMarried", $("#IsMarried").val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../User/SaveFirstWebForm",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#loading_div').hide();
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

**In the Controller side, this is the method that receives the call:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveFirstWebForm(WebApplicationFirstPhase model)
    {
        string Nme = model.FirstName + model.LastName;
        bool ArmedFBit = model.IsMarried;//this is always true!
        return Json("");
    }
```

Comment: As far as creating radio buttons for a `bool` property in your model, I think that looks right.  Have you verified that these elements are in the form? `@using (Html.BeginForm(...)) { //form elements in the using block }`

Comment: @chadnt I did, but let me double check

Comment: @chadnt yes, everything looks correct in the form and it is still passing true even when I click No

Comment: What you claiming is not possible based on the code you have shown - its due to code you have not shown (one possible cause would be if you have included a hidden input for `IsMarried` before the radio buttons)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you, I added the other code to show you everything related to this property. Nothing hidden in the form, I hope I was able to explain everything.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad I was able to explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the jquery selector setting.

You can try to use

```
$('input[name=IsMarried]:checked').val()
```

instead of

```
$("#IsMarried").val()
```

get the value, because you want to get radio button, which was checked.